Why is this JS module imported with a "default" property in TypeScript?
This code from a custom i18n module, located in ./esm/locale/en.js:
import cardinal from '../rules/rule5';
import ordinal from '../rules/rule42';
var pluralRule = {
  ordinal: ordinal,
  cardinal: cardinal,
};
export default pluralRule;

Is exported in package.json with
{
  "exports": {
    "./en": {
       "default": "./esm/locale/en.js",
    }
  }
}

The i18n module is installed as dependency in a project, and used as
// some .ts file in the project
import en from 'custom-i18n/en';

console.log(en);
// { default: [Getter] }

Why is en having { default } instead of { ordinal, cardinal }?

How are you building the project that uses the custom-i18n dependency? Is there a build for the custom-i18n package? Are both built to ES modules? You've left out some important details that could help get you an answer. The fact that you left off the extensions for the relative specifiers in the imports for the ./esm/locale/en.js file implies there is a build behind the custom i18n package. It would be helpful to see those details.

Looks like your custom-i18n is probably producing a CJS build with something like this in the built file exports.default = pluralRule;. Is your exports really pointing to an ES module or CJS?

If you actually want to build to ES modules, then you will most likely encounter this TS error: `src/index.ts:1:31 - error TS2835: Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in ECMAScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './locale/af.js'?
1 export { default as af } from "./locale/af";
`

@morganney Thank you for your comments. The code posted in the question is all the relevant code that is loaded/executed. FYI there is a CJS module being produced as well, but that file is never loaded by TypeScript. The project uses tsx as launcher. I never encountered the error you suggested, no.

Still some unknowns so hard to answer because I feel in the dark. This is not your i18n repo on GitHub then that we’re talking about? The error was produced by running an esm build of the plurals package.

@morganney if you are wise enough to look for that repo, the local changes have not yet been pushed, so there are changes in the build process from what you may see at this time. I'll update the answer with the actual source. I thought it would be simpler :/

Your question seemed fun, and I had some time to kill before bed, so I dug a little deeper. Isn't open source software great ;)!? You can see a very basic example that will get the output you expected here: https://github.com/morganney/tsexports

You can see an example in a pull request I've opened against your project that gives the output you expect when running console.log.
Two significant changes are:

Add "type": "module" to the plurals package.json file.
Add the necessary file extensions to your relative import specifiers.

Other changes related to your build are:

Prefer tsx over ts-node to circumvent an unknown file extension error when running generate.ts.
Make sure to copy over the type field from package.json while running your build scripts.

Debugging/Testing related changes:

Added apps/demo-next/file.js and apps/demo-next/file.tsx.

After building the base package, and then the plurals package, you should be able to run these commands from the root of the repository:

node apps/demo-next/file.js
./node_modules/.bin/tsx apps/demo-next/file.tsx

To yield the following output:
{ ordinal: [Function: default], cardinal: [Function: default] }

I was able to reproduce the { default: [Getter] } console output you asked about by executing a .ts file with the example code shown in the question before making the changes in the pull request, but I didn't dig too much into why. I'm guessing tsx is defaulting to your main field for the plurals package which points to a CJS build that produces this output:
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};

var en_1 = require("./locale/en");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "en", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return __importDefault(en_1).default; } });


FWIW, there is a package I authored that makes building dual packages with TypeScript relatively easy: @knighted/duel

Thank you so much for the boost! Yes, open source is awesome!
